# Double decimal values

Tags: java

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
float resultTime= (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
System.out.println("Result time : " + resultTime);
```

The result is always a rounded value like *1.0* or *2.0*.
How can I obtain an exact result like *1.234*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java float division precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286681/java-float-division-precision)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing integer division. (which rounds down to an integer)

Cast to `float` before you do the division:

```
float resultTime= (float)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0f;
```

Comment: That should be ...` / 1000.0f` should it not? It's the denominator that determines the return value.

Comment: Doing `System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime / 1000.0f` would probably be less ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dividing by 1000, divide by 1000.0. That way instead of doing integer division, you do floating point division.