# java- issue in getting correct value with decimal

Tags: java

I am trying to get exact calculated value (in my case it should be 66.66... not 66.0) but it prints 66.0

If I will get 66.66 then I can use Math.round(66.66) so that I will get 67

Below code after execution should return 66.66 but it returns 66.0

```
double d = (2*100)/3
```

Please suggest..

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my java division code give the wrong answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286681/why-does-my-java-division-code-give-the-wrong-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers suggested , you can provide at least one floating number. Or if you don't want to change the numbers, you can add cast to the numerator

```
double d=   (double)(2*100)/3;
System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
  66.66666666666667
```

Comment: You are not actually casting the RESULT to a `double`, rather, you are casting the NUMERATOR (e.g. `(2*100)`) to a `double`

Comment: I was trying (2*100/3) and was not using type casting (double). I think that was issue.    double d= (double)(2*100)/3 returns expected result.

Answer (score 3):

`(2*100)/3` performs integer multiplication and division, which results in an integer.

You need to force floating point calculation by changing one of the operands to an double (or float):

```
double d = (2.0*100)/3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using all int values in your arithmetic operation so final result will always be int and when you put it into a double then it becomes 66.0. But since original result is int, so you loose precision.

You can use `double d = (2.0*100.0)/3.0;` or have at least one value with decimal point, so that you can get expected decimal points.

Number after decimal point is commonly known as **precision**. So, the issue which you talked about is commonly known as **floating-point imprecision**, and in your case you can call it as double-point imprecision.

**Rule of thumb:**

1. If either is of type double, the other is converted to double for arithmetic operation and final result will be a double.
2. Otherwise, if either is a float, the other is converted to float for arithmetic operation and final result will be a float.
3. Otherwise, if either is of type long, the other is converted to long for arithmetic operation and final result will be a long.
4. Otherwise, both operands are converted to int for arithmetic operation and final result will be a int.

Comment: @SSingh: Have you got your answer, if not then please write your answer so that other's can be benefited from it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

As Eran says it's your expression perform integer arithmetic you need to perform like

`double d = (double) (2*100)/3;`

if needs format the result.