# Arithmetic Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a code that computes the following for a given integer **`n`**:

```
1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ... + 1/n
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
public class RecursiveSum
{
  public static double Sumto(int n)
  {
    if (n == 0) { return 0.0; }
    else if (n > 0) { return 1/n + 1/Sumto(n - 1); }
    else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide positive integers"); }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(Sumto(5));
  }
}
```

However, it always outputs:

```
Infinity
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of recursion a for-loop over 1 to n might be simpler and less error-prone here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two issues :

You must perform floating point division (i.e. replace `1/n` with `1.0/n`), and you should add `Sumto(n - 1)` to `1.0/n` to get `Sumto(n)`.

```
  public static double Sumto(int n)
  {
    if (n == 0) { return 0.0; }
    else if (n > 0) { return 1.0/n + Sumto(n - 1); }
    else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide positive integers"); }
  }
```

The reason you got `Infinity` was that `1/Sumto(n - 1)` returns `Infinity` when `Sumto(n - 1)` is `0.0`, and `Sumto(0)` is `0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

> However, it always outputs: Infinity

Because you are doing `1/0` in the following steps in your code which yields `Infinity`.

```
else if (n > 0) { return 1/n + 1/Sumto(n - 1);
```

You thought `n > 0` escapes the `n / 0` stuffs, but nope! Think about the case when `n = 1` which passes `n > 0` case but fall into a trap to:

```
1/Sumto(n - 1)
1/Sumto(1 - 1)
1/Sumto(0)
```

where `Sumto(0)` returns `0.0`. Hence,

```
 1/0.0
```

yields `Infinity`. Moreover, use `1.0/n` instead of `1/n` as it is [floating point division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286681/why-does-my-java-division-code-give-the-wrong-answer).

So add another condition, like

```
if(n == 1) 
    return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few problems, nothing first that since there is no *closed form* expression for the harmonic series.

1. You need to compute each term using *floating point* division. Rewrite as `1.0 / n`.
2. Drop the term `1.0 / 0` as that will give you an infinite floating point value.
3. **You'll get better accuracy if you reverse the loop.** That is, compute the smaller terms first. Otherwise you'll underestimate the sum with floating point arithmetic. As a rule of thumb, always add small numbers first.