# Not getting the correct math result

Tags: java

When doing the following in Java, i get as the result 0.0. Even though the result should be 10. This is an example calculation, in my code it's doing this with with *double* values.

```
double result = (10 / 100) * 100;
```

Comment: Because `10 / 100 = 0`.

Comment: @WesleyEgbertsen: No, it doesn't. Not when you're doing integer arithmetic, which is what happens when both operands of `/` are `int`.

Comment: I lot of people are using [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double) as a close-target (here and on several other questions). Frankly, it seems like a really poor one. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286681/why-does-my-java-division-code-give-the-wrong-answer) is a bit better.

Answer (score 7):

`10` and `100` are integer literals, so `10 / 100` is evaluated in *integer arithmetic* which means that any remainder is discarded.

So you get `(10 / 100) * 100 = (0) * 100`

One fix is to *promote* one of the arguments to a double:

`(10.0 / 100) * 100`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double result = (10.0 / 100) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with integer and int 10 / int 100 is 0. 0 * 100 is also 0