# return an integer that has been st inside a for loop

Tags: java

I have to create a method in `JAVA` where a user define a number, and the method search inside an array how many time this number exists, like this:

```
int[] age = {21, 23, 21, 29, 18};
```

If the user enters: `21`
The output should be:

> 21 exist 2 times

I made this code:

```
public static int numAgeReader(int[] ageToSearch)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        int counter=0;
        System.out.println("Please enter an age:");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        //Searching the ages Array to see how many persons have this age
        for(int i=0; i<ageToSearch.length; i++)
        {
            if(n==ageToSearch[i])
                counter += counter; //counter = counter + 1
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

And of course I called it in the main function:

```
System.out.println(numAgeReader(ages));
```

Where ages is the array that I previously filled it.

The result is always: `0`

**EDIT**

This method should return an average of an array:

```
public static double average(int[] ageArray)
    {
        //double aver=0.0;
        int sum = 0;
        //Calculating the sum of the age array
        for (int i=0; i<ageArray.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + ageArray[i];
        }
        //Calculating the average:
        return(sum/ageArray.length);
        //return aver;
    }
```

The result should be sometimes like 25.33 or 18.91, but the returned value is always like this: 25.0 or 19.0 or 89.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
counter += counter;
```

to

```
counter++;
```

Since `counter` is set to **0** at the beginning, `counter += counter;` has no effect on the `counter` variable, hence you'll always get **0** as the return value.

Comment: sir, I have a function that return the average I want this average to be like 25.33 and not like 25.00, the variable is double how to fix that ?

Comment: @androidnation update your post with the code of the function that you are talking about. Even though, I highly advise you to do more research about it.

Comment: @androidnation change `return(sum/ageArray.length);` to `return((double)sum/ageArray.length);`. Check this link for more about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286681/why-does-my-java-division-code-give-the-wrong-answer

Comment: @androidnation you're doing something wrong. Try to do more research, if you couldn't figure it on your own, post a new question with your problem in details. Good luck !

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake here:

```
counter += counter;
```

You probably meant:

```
counter++;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing `counter += counter` you are actually adding 0 to itself every time.

You need to write 
`counter++` or `counter += 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
   counter++;
```

Instead of `counter += counter;`